# How to highlight a selected item in the LongListSelector on WP8?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

How is it possible to highlight the selected item in the new LongListSelector on Windows Phone 8? Actually nothing happend if I tapped one entry of the list. My list only contains a simple string which will be displayed through a TextBlock. But I want to highlight the selection of the user.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In my case I used a `RadioButton`Control in the `DataTemplate` of the `LongListSelectorItem` to achieve this. You will have a checked oder unchecked sign at the left border.

In any case it is important, that you set the same group for all Radiobuttons, so the selection only represents one entry.

Inside the `Content`or your `RadioButton` you can put the `TextBlock` bound to the `String`.

Im currently not at home, but if this wont solve your problem, I'll provide you some code when I'm at home ;)

Here you go:

```
<LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ContentControl HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
            <RadioButton HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" GroupName="A" Background="Black" >
                <StackPanel toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=XXX}" 
                               TextWrapping="Wrap"
                               Foreground="Black" 
                               Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=XXXX}" 
                               TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                               Foreground="Black" 
                               Margin="14,-6,0,0" 
                               Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </RadioButton>
        </ContentControl>
    </DataTemplate>
</LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Added the Code in my initial answer.

Comment: Can you please help me on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22706930/long-list-selector-with-item-tap-animation