# How to Create Border around LongListSelector SelectedItem

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

I would like to create a border around the currently selected item within a `LongListSelector`, but I am having trouble getting the proper implementation. From referencing http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Highlight-a-selected-item-30ced444 I have tried to follow the sample code by creating a custom `Style` to manage the selected item change, although I am trying to place a border around an image instead of a textbox. Also, I do have a custom `ItemTemplate` as my `DataTemplate` for my `LongListSelector` which manages the size of my bound images and controls a required `ContextMenu` for each item.

For some reason, I am having trouble adapting the sample to place a border around a selected item, but what I have so far is as follows

MainPage.xaml

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
        <!--<Border x:Name="brd" CornerRadius="10" BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" Width="Auto" BorderThickness="3">-->
        <Border x:Name="brd" CornerRadius="10" Width="Auto" BorderThickness="3">
            <Viewbox Width="108" Height="108">
                <Image x:Name="recentImage" Source="{Binding Source}" Margin="6,6" Width="108"/>
            </Viewbox>
            <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                <toolkit:ContextMenu x:Name="imgListContextMenu" Background="{StaticResource PhoneChromeBrush}">
                    <toolkit:MenuItem Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" Header="edit" Click="editContextMenuItem_Click"/>
                    <toolkit:MenuItem Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" Header="favorite" Click="favoriteContextMenuItem_Click"/>
                    <toolkit:MenuItem Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" Header="delete" Click="deleteContextMenuItem_Click"/>
                </toolkit:ContextMenu>
            </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

...

<phone:LongListSelector x:Name="Recent" Margin="0" 
                                    Style="{StaticResource MyLongListSelectorStyle}"
                                    SelectionChanged="recent_SelectionChanged" 
                                    toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True"
                                    LayoutMode="Grid" GridCellSize="108,108"
                                    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}"
                                    />
```

App.xaml

```
<Style x:Key="MyLongListSelectorStyle" TargetType="phone:LongListSelector" >
        <!--<Setter Property="LayoutMode" Value="List"/>-->
        <Setter Property="LayoutMode" Value="Grid"/>
        <!--<Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Times New Roman"/>-->
        <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <UserControl>
                        <Border x:Name="MyBorder" Background="Transparent">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups  >
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background)" Storyboard.TargetName="MyBorder">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <!--<StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" Text="{Binding}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                            </StackPanel>-->
                        </Border>
                    </UserControl>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
private void recent_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var s = sender as LongListSelector;
        var item = (sender as LongListSelector).SelectedItem;
        if (item == null)
            return;

        // Get item of LongListSelector.
        List<UserControl> listItems = new List<UserControl>();
        GetItemsRecursive<UserControl>(Recent, ref listItems);

        // Selected.
        if (e.AddedItems.Count > 0 && e.AddedItems[0] != null)
        {
            foreach (UserControl userControl in listItems)
            {
                if (e.AddedItems[0].Equals(userControl.DataContext))
                {
                    VisualStateManager.GoToState(userControl, "Selected", true);
                }
            }
        }
        // Unselected.
        if (e.RemovedItems.Count > 0 && e.RemovedItems[0] != null)
        {
            foreach (UserControl userControl in listItems)
            {
                if (e.RemovedItems[0].Equals(userControl.DataContext))
                {
                    VisualStateManager.GoToState(userControl, "Normal", true);
                }
            }
        }
    }

public static void GetItemsRecursive<T>(DependencyObject parents, ref List<T> objectList) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        var childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parents);

        for (int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parents, i);

            if (child is T)
            {
                objectList.Add(child as T);
            }

            GetItemsRecursive<T>(child, ref objectList);
        }

        return;
    }
```

I'm stuck on what to do from here, any ideas?

EDIT** slightly changed implementation but still not working.

MainPage.xaml

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

    <Style x:Key="MyLongListSelectorStyle" TargetType="phone:LongListSelector" >
        <!--<Setter Property="LayoutMode" Value="List"/>-->
        <Setter Property="LayoutMode" Value="Grid"/>
        <!--<Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Times New Roman"/>-->
        <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <UserControl>
                        <!--<Border x:Name="MyBorder" Background="Transparent">-->
                        <Border x:Name="MyBorder" Background="Transparent">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups  >
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <!--<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background)" Storyboard.TargetName="MyBorder">-->
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness" Storyboard.TargetName="brd">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Border x:Name="brd" CornerRadius="10" Width="Auto" BorderThickness="3">
                                <!--<Border x:Name="brd" CornerRadius="10" Width="Auto" BorderThickness="3">-->
                                <Viewbox Width="108" Height="108">
                                    <Image x:Name="recentImage" Source="{Binding Source}" Margin="6,6" Width="108"/>
                                </Viewbox>
                                <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                                    <toolkit:ContextMenu x:Name="imgListContextMenu" Background="{StaticResource PhoneChromeBrush}">
                                        <toolkit:MenuItem Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" Header="edit" Click="editContextMenuItem_Click"/>
                                        <toolkit:MenuItem Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" Header="favorite" Click="favoriteContextMenuItem_Click"/>
                                        <toolkit:MenuItem Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" Header="delete" Click="deleteContextMenuItem_Click"/>
                                    </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                                </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                            </Border>
                            <!--<StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" Text="{Binding}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                            </StackPanel>-->
                        </Border>
                    </UserControl>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

...

<phone:LongListSelector x:Name="Recent" Margin="0" 
                                    Style="{StaticResource MyLongListSelectorStyle}"
                                    SelectionChanged="recent_SelectionChanged" 
                                    toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True"
                                    LayoutMode="Grid" GridCellSize="108,108"

                                    />
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
//remains the same
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't test it rigth now because I'm at work and I only have VS2010 but try changing

```
<DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
```

You need to use an integer.
You are trying to change the thickness of the border using a color.

```
<DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="3"/>
```

**[EDIT]**

It seems that LongListSelector don't let us easily template the selected item...
With the solution of [Johannes Wanzek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1397886/johannes-wanzek) https://stackoverflow.com/a/13874389/1408558
I managed to do what you want:

Delete your old xaml and code behind code, and follow these steps.

You need to put those styles on top of your page

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="PhoneButtonBase" TargetType="ButtonBase">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBorderThickness}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMedium}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,5,10,6"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ButtonBase">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneButtonBasePressedForegroundBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="ButtonBackground" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="0" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}">
                            <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="PhoneRadioButtonCheckBoxBase" BasedOn="{StaticResource PhoneButtonBase}" TargetType="ToggleButton">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PhoneRadioCheckBoxBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PhoneRadioCheckBoxBorderBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMedium}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="RadioButtonStyle1" BasedOn="{StaticResource PhoneRadioButtonCheckBoxBase}" TargetType="RadioButton">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Checked"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

And then use the LongListSelector like this:

```
        <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="Recent" Margin="0"
            toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True"
            LayoutMode="Grid" GridCellSize="108,108" >

            <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ContentControl HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
                        <ContentControl.Resources>
                            <Storyboard x:Name="CheckedStoryboard">
                                <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="Red" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="brd" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </ContentControl.Resources>
                        <RadioButton x:Name="radioButton" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" GroupName="A" Background="Black" Style="{StaticResource RadioButtonStyle1}" >
                            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                                    <eim:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource CheckedStoryboard}"/>
                                </i:EventTrigger>
                                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Unchecked">
                                    <eim:ControlStoryboardAction ControlStoryboardOption="Stop" Storyboard="{StaticResource CheckedStoryboard}"/>
                                </i:EventTrigger>
                            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <Border x:Name="MyBorder" Background="Transparent">
                                <Border x:Name="brd" CornerRadius="10" Width="Auto" BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="Transparent">
                                    <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                                        <toolkit:ContextMenu x:Name="imgListContextMenu" Background="{StaticResource PhoneChromeBrush}">
                                            <toolkit:MenuItem Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" Header="edit"/>
                                            <toolkit:MenuItem Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" Header="favorite"/>
                                            <toolkit:MenuItem Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" Header="delete"/>
                                        </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                                    </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                                    <Viewbox Width="108" Height="108">
                                        <Image x:Name="recentImage" Source="{Binding Source}" Margin="6,6" Width="108"/>
                                    </Viewbox>
                                </Border>
                            </Border>
                        </RadioButton>
                    </ContentControl>
                </DataTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>

        </phone:LongListSelector>
```

And here some of the namespaces you may need:

```
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
xmlns:eim="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Media;assembly=Microsoft.Expression.Interactions"
```

[image]

Comment: That is a good point I must have looked over. Preferably, I do not want to change the border thickness because it will cause the other items to move slightly when the border shows up, I would like to just switch between a brush of `Transparent` when unselected to `PhoneAccentBrush` when selected.

Comment: Little rectification, I've use the Red color. If you want to use the Phone accent Brush, change the CheckedStoryboard by 
        `<Storyboard x:Name="CheckedStoryboard">
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="brd">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>`

Comment: One question, if the page where the selection is occuring is navigated from, how would I programmatically unselect the item? I've noticed that with my implementation, when navigating from the page, if I have N items in the LongListSelector and the nth item is selected, then when navigating back to the page the N-n item has the border shown even though the nth item is still the one actually currently selected?

Comment: To remove selection try : `LongListSelector.SelectedItem = null`

Comment: That does remove the item programmatically, although the border still exists for some reason?

Comment: Can you please help me on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22706930/long-list-selector-with-item-tap-animation

Answer (score 0):

Check out my alternative answer here [How to highlight the selected item of long list selector in windows phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20656731/how-to-highlight-the-selected-item-of-long-list-selector-in-windows-phone-8/24904844#24904844)

It shows the example for the background color but could just as easily be adapted for the border color of something

Might not be the ideal way to do it but its simple and clean and works for me