# How to Control StoryBoard in Code Behind

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, storyboard

Upon a button click event, I am showing a border around an item in a LongListSelector. I have having an issue, however, when leaving the page and then returning. When leaving, I would like to programmatically unselect the item (which is working) but the border around the item still shows when returning to the page. How might I remove the border as well? This is very confusing when a user expects no item to be selected when the original page is loaded, whether it be from application start or from being navigated to from another page.

MainPage.xaml

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

    <Style x:Key="PhoneButtonBase" TargetType="ButtonBase">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBorderThickness}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMedium}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,5,10,6"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ButtonBase">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneButtonBasePressedForegroundBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="ButtonBackground" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="0" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}">
                            <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="PhoneRadioButtonCheckBoxBase" BasedOn="{StaticResource PhoneButtonBase}" TargetType="ToggleButton">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PhoneRadioCheckBoxBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PhoneRadioCheckBoxBorderBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMedium}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="RadioButtonStyle1" BasedOn="{StaticResource PhoneRadioButtonCheckBoxBase}" TargetType="RadioButton">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Checked"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

...

<phone:LongListSelector x:Name="Recent" Margin="0,0,0,72"
                                    LayoutMode="Grid" GridCellSize="108,108" 
                                    SelectionChanged="recent_SelectionChanged">

                <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ContentControl HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
                            <ContentControl.Resources>
                                <Storyboard x:Name="CheckedStoryboard">
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FF1BA1E2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="brd" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </ContentControl.Resources>
                            <RadioButton x:Name="radioButton" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" GroupName="A" Background="Black" Style="{StaticResource RadioButtonStyle1}" >
                                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                                        <eim:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource CheckedStoryboard}"/>
                                    </i:EventTrigger>
                                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Unchecked">
                                        <eim:ControlStoryboardAction ControlStoryboardOption="Stop" Storyboard="{StaticResource CheckedStoryboard}"/>
                                    </i:EventTrigger>
                                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                <Border x:Name="MyBorder" Background="Transparent">
                                    <Border x:Name="brd" CornerRadius="10" Width="Auto" BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="Transparent">
                                        <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                                            <toolkit:ContextMenu x:Name="imgListContextMenu" Background="{StaticResource PhoneChromeBrush}">
                                                <toolkit:MenuItem Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" Header="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.MainPage_ContextMenu_Delete, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" Click="deleteContextMenuItem_Click"/>
                                            </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                                        </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu> 
                                        <Viewbox Width="108" Height="108">
                                            <Image x:Name="recentImage" Source="{Binding Source}" Margin="0" Width="108"/>
                                        </Viewbox>
                                    </Border>
                                </Border>
                            </RadioButton>
                        </ContentControl>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>

            </phone:LongListSelector>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);

        //Removes the selected item, but the border still shows when returning to the page?
        Recent.SelectedItem = null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You've shown a lot of code but most of it doesn't seem to be relevant to your actual question. You also haven't made it clear how you're highlighting the selected item.

Based on the limited information you've provided I'd guess that you're using code to trigger changing of the state/style of the item.
You're then changing the SelectedItem property on the list but you haven't bound this to anything and so it makes no change.

The simplest solution would be to bind to the selected item and have a different state when selected.
Alternatively, if you really want to use a button press to trigger the highlighting, you'll need remove this highlighting in a similar way. That is, on page exit you clear the highlighting from whatever item is highlighted. This could be done by walking the visual tree to identify the highlighted item, or having a [bound] property on the underlying viewmodel which you can query/update.

Comment: Well, I was having trouble with the highlighting of the selected item, but with a little help on a question I recently asked it was solved here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18436328/how-to-create-border-around-longlistselector-selecteditem . I have no code behind to trigger the changing state/style of the item. I just set `Recent.SelectedItem = null;` to programmatically unselect the item from the LongListSelector. The only problem is, the border remains?