# How to highlight the selected item of long list selector in windows phone 8

Tags: list, windows-phone-8, listitem, longlistselector, selectlistitem

I've developed Windows Phone 8 application. In that I'm using the Long list selector to display items in the list. Everything is fine up till now. When the user clicks on any item of long list selector, I want to highlight that item's background color, so that the user clearly understands that he/she has selected an item.

Could you please tell me how to do this in windows phone 8. 
I'm looking forward for the response.

Answer (score 3):

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Highlight-a-selected-item-30ced444
Detailed example of how to do it

Answer (score 0):

I like to have more control of my application through code and avoid doing things in the xaml where it can get complicated. Below is a simpler way I feel and gives more control in code and require minimal changes in the xaml. It keeps the xaml nice and clean for what should be a really simple action.

1. Add a "BackColor" (or other string) property to your bound object

   ```
   public string BackColor { get; set; }
   ```
2. Bind that property to something in your xaml like the background or a stack panel or the border color of a border, something that will present the visual change. E.g.

   ```
   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="{Binding BackColor}">
   ```
3. In your long list selector code "SelectionChanged" event update the bound objects using the AddedItems and RemovedItems collections from SelectionChangedEventArgs e

   ```
   if (e.AddedItems.Count > 0)
   {
       if (e.AddedItems[0] != null)
       {
           oMyObject = (MyServices.MyObjectDao)e.AddedItems[0];
           oMyObject.BackColor = "Red";
       }
   }

   if (e.RemovedItems.Count > 0)
   {
       if (e.RemovedItems[0] != null)
       {
           oMyObject = (MySercvices.MyObjectDao)e.RemovedItems[0];
           oMyObject.BackColor = "Black";
       }
   }
   ```

You can use simple colors like in the example, or you can use any predefined colors from your xaml